# TFS how to exclude DLLs and code comments/white spaces from Code Review

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

In my team we are using TFS for code review. Unfortunately the UI in VS Team Explorer and the Team Foundation Web interface are pretty ugly and unfriendly, e.g. dlls packages need to be collapsed one by one and that makes Code Reviews tedious as you end up having to chase the relevant code.

Is there any way I can exclude files (e.g. DLLs) or have more advanced filter (e.g. exclude comments, white spaces, new lines)?

Thanks

Comment: Don't put binaries in source control. It's a bad practice. Use a package manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to simply exclude  source controlled DLLS from Code Review.

*Daniel* is right, for this kind of external dlls, the best and clean way is via the package management solution such as NuGet. There is an excellent extension called-- Package Management in TFS. It's not hard and will not take too much time to do this.

> **Package Management** is an extension that makes it easy to discover, install, and publish packages. It's deeply integrated with other Team
>   Services and TFS hubs like Build so that package management can become
>   a seamless part of your existing workflows.

For more details, you could have a look at this tutorial-- [**Package Management in Team Services and TFS**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/overview)

Besides, there is also not any built-in advanced filter (e.g. exclude comments, white spaces, new lines). The official tutorial for your reference: [Get your code reviewed with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=vsts)

You could also try to use some 3-rd party extension in VS such as this one: [Review Assistant - Code Review Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevartSoftware.ReviewAssistant-CodeReviewTool)  which also support TFS integraton.